# How to prevent CSS for popup conflicting index.html CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm attempting to use a form from codepen user Kyle Lavery [sign up modal](http://codepen.io/koenigsegg1/pen/wGoRRR) as a popup. I'm using `<?php include"contact.html"; ?>` in my index.html. My problem is that contact.html has `overflow: hidden` applied to the `body` which is conflicting with index.html. It's also possible that the styles applied to  `*, :before, :after` are an issue but so far I can't tell. I tried putting a div around the entire form and it's parent divs and applying the styling from `body` to it but that cause the animation to shake slightly. Any suggestions on how to to apply this CSS while still keeping the animation smooth? My next thought is to use jQuery to only apply this CSS when the popup opens onclick. View the snippet full-screen to see the animation properly.

```js
$(".close, .nope").on('click', function () {
  $('.modal').addClass('hidden');
  $('.open').addClass('active');
})

$(".open").on('click', function () {
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  $('.modal').removeClass('hidden');
})
```

```css
*, :before, :after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
          transition: 0.4s;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.popup {
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

.modal {
  height: 450px;
  width: 650px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .4s, box-shadow .3s .4s;
          transition: .4s, box-shadow .3s .4s;
}
.modal.hidden {
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transition: .4s, box-shadow 0s;
          transition: .4s, box-shadow 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  visibility: hidden;
}
.modal.hidden .form {
  top: 100%;
}
.modal.hidden .invite {
  top: -100%;
}
.modal.hidden .invite .close {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.form, .invite {
  background: rgba(71, 71, 71, 0.8);
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

input {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px;
}
input:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 500px #7a7a7a inset;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #FFF;
}

label {
  font: 500 14px Roboto;
  color: #ffb66e;
}

button {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #f04527, #ffb66e);
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #f04527, #ffb66e);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 21px;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}
button:hover:before {
  left: 110%;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
          transition: .3s;
}
button:before {
  content: '';
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  height: 100%;
  width: 65px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: skew(-45deg);
          transform: skew(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0s;
          transition: 0s;
}

.invite {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(135deg, #f04527, #ffb66e);
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #f04527, #ffb66e);
  left: 50%;
}

h2 {
  font: 30px Roboto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.close {
  background: #474747;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .4s .3s;
          transition: .4s .3s;
}
.close:before, .close:after {
  content: '';
  background: #FFF;
  height: 80%;
  width: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
.close:after {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.open {
  color: black;
  height: 45px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  visibility: hidden;
}
.open.active {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Daily UI #001 - Sign Up Modal</title>


    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/contact.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="popup">
        <a class="open active" title="open modal" href="#">Open Modal</a>
        <div class="modal hidden">
            <div class="form">
                <form>
                    <label for="first-name" required="required">First Name</label>
                    <input id="first-name" type="text" />
                    <label for="last-name" required="required">Last Name</label>
                    <input id="last-name" type="text" />
                    <label for="email" required="required">Email Address</label>
                    <input id="email" type="email" />
                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <input id="message" type="text" />
                    <button type="button">Send</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="invite">
                <h2>Thank you for your interest. I look forward to speaking with you soon.</h2>
                <div title="close" class="close"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/contact.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is the conflict?

Comment: It causes many of the elements to not display and you can't scroll down to view anything outside of the initial range of the viewport. I thought I had provided enough information without providing the index.html as well. Let me know if you think I should post that too.